# SendAsync runs but the data is not really sent

Tags: c#, asyncsocket, sendasync

I have an application that communicate through sockets using the *Async methods (like [SendAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.sendasync.aspx)). I'm getting this strange behavior where SendAsync is executed but the data is not sent over the wire.

I've enabled network tracing and got the following log:

```
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [4300] Socket#5024928::SendAsync()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [4300] Socket#5024928::SendAsync(Boolean#1)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7320] Data from Socket#5024928::FinishOperation(SendAsync)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7320] 00000E8C : 01 99 27 00 00 00 01 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : ..'.............
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7320] 00000E9C : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : ................
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7320] 00000EAC : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : ................
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7320] 00000EBC : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : ................
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7320] 00000ECC : 00 00 B3 F4                                     : ....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7320] Socket#5024928::ReceiveAsync()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7320] Exiting Socket#5024928::ReceiveAsync()   -> Boolean#1
System.Net.Sockets Error: 0 : [7320] Socket#5024928::UpdateStatusAfterSocketError() - TimedOut
```

Although the trace shows that the data was sent (and a receive timeout occurred), the data was not really sent. I've checked with Microsoft's Network Monitor and there's no log of this data being sent.

The send method is pretty straightfoward:

```
 public void Send(AsyncClientState state, byte[] data) {
            var socket = state.Socket;
            var dataTransferredEventArgs = new DataTransferredEventArgs(data, _maxBytes) { State = state };
            state.Events.RaiseBeforeSend(dataTransferredEventArgs);
            byte[] bytesToSend = dataTransferredEventArgs.Bytes.ToArray();
            SocketAsyncEventArgs args = GetSocketAsyncEventArgsArgs(socket, bytesToSend.Length);
            if (args == null) {
                state.Events.RaiseTimeout(Operation.Send);
                return;
            }
            args.Completed += SendCompleted;
            args.UserToken = state;
            Buffer.BlockCopy(bytesToSend, 0, args.Buffer, args.Offset, bytesToSend.Length);
            bool sendAsync = socket.SendAsync(args);
            if (!sendAsync) {
                SendCompleted(this, args);
            }
        }

        private void SendCompleted(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e) {
            var state = (AsyncClientState) e.UserToken;
            var events = state.Events;
            try {
                if (e.SocketError != SocketError.Success) {
                    events.RaiseError(new ErrorEventArgs("(SendSocketError)" + e.SocketError));
                    return;
                }
                if (e.LastOperation == SocketAsyncOperation.Send) {
                    e.Completed -= SendCompleted;
                    _asyncEventArgsPool.PutBack(e);
                    events.RaiseAfterSend(new StateEventArgs(state));
                }
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException) { }
            catch (SocketException ex) {
                events.RaiseError(new ErrorEventArgs(string.Format("{0}: {1}", ex.SocketErrorCode, ex.Message)));
            }
        }
```

Am I missing something here? Is the network tracing really reliable?

**UPDATE**

I tried to use Begin/End*, but still the same problem. Here is the trace:

```
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [6632] Socket#29357909::BeginSend()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [6632] Exiting Socket#29357909::BeginSend()     -> OverlappedAsyncResult#30136159
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [6500] Data from Socket#29357909::PostCompletion
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [6500] 00000000 : 01 99 27 00 00 00 01 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : ..'.............
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [6500] 00000010 : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : ................
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [6500] 00000020 : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : ................
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [6500] 00000030 : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : ................
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [6500] 00000040 : 00 00 B3 F4                                     : ....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [6500] Socket#29357909::EndSend(OverlappedAsyncResult#30136159)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [6500] Exiting Socket#29357909::EndSend()   -> Int32#68
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [6500] Socket#29357909::BeginReceive()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [6500] Exiting Socket#29357909::BeginReceive()  -> OverlappedAsyncResult#63504289
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [6500] Socket#29357909::EndReceive(OverlappedAsyncResult#63504289)
System.Net.Sockets Error: 0 : [6500] Socket#29357909::UpdateStatusAfterSocketError() - TimedOut
System.Net.Sockets Error: 0 : [6500] Exception in Socket#29357909::EndReceive - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [6500] Exiting Socket#29357909::EndReceive()    -> Int32#0
```

Comment: Have you checked the contents of arg before calling SendAsync?

Comment: @Jani not sure if I understood you, but the content is correct (as per the trace)

Comment: Another thought: don't you have any firewall or antivirus on you system which might block the app.

Comment: @Jani just windows firewall, but I'm not sure if this is the case. This block is a part of the communication. Before this occurs, about 7 or 8 messages were exchanged between server and client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to our network administrator, we found that the problem was a network misconfiguration. I'm not "into" networking but the problem was related to the fact that the equipment I was communicating were into our DMZ.